# How to create a condition with TWIG and Drupal 8 to check the type of store?

Tags: templates, twig, drupal-8, drupal-commerce

I have a Drupal Site 8 with Drupal Commerce. I create 2 types of store:

- personal_store
- professional_store

I'm working on the template of my products and I want to display the code above only if the parent store is of type store_professional

Is it possible ?

How to create a condition with TWIG and Drupal 8 to check the type of store?

Here is the code that I want to put in the templates of my products only if the parent store is of type store_professional :

```
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 bs-region-legal">
    <div class="panel panel-success">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Informations légales</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-cgv" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-cgv">
              <i class="fas fa-signature fa-lg"></i> Conditions générales de vente
            </button>
            <div class="modal fade" id="modal-cgv" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Conditions générales de vente">
              <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="Partager">Conditions générales de vente</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    {{ store.field_professionnel_cgv }}
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-shipping-methods" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-shipping-methods">
              <i class="fas fa-truck fa-lg"></i> Modes de livraison
            </button>
            <div class="modal fade" id="modal-shipping-methods" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Modes de livraison">
              <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="Partager">Modes de livraison</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    {{ store.field_professionnel_livraison }}
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-payment-gateways" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-payment-gateways">
              <i class="fas fa-credit-card fa-lg"></i> Modes de paiement
            </button>
            <div class="modal fade" id="modal-payment-gateways" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Modes de paiement">
              <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="Partager">Modes de paiement</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    {{ store.field_professionnel_paiement }}
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a field called "type" in your store? If yes, you can simply check like this:

```
{% if store.type == "store_professional" %}
```

Comment: thanks it works. A question, if I create a store view page. How to get the same rule in the template of the view ?

Comment: https://ibb.co/1ry4b4h Sorry, finally it does not work, if I do the following code, the block does not appear for `professionnel` type stores `{% if store.type == "professionnel" %} 
    {{ drupal_view('cgv_boutique', 'block_1') }}
  {% endif %}`

Comment: Yes, sure! When you create your view, you have to send your store object to the page. In there you can check the same way, because you'd have your same object store.

Comment: What's the real string for your store type? 'store_professional' or 'professional' ?